# Cadastro feito um em cima do outro!

Tags: vue.js, electron

Estou com um problema. Estou usando o `lokijs` com `vuejs`, para cadastrar um usuário via modal, até ai tudo bem, só que toda a vez que eu cadastro um novo usuário, esse novo cadastro substitui o antigo. Como resolvo isso?

RENDERER

```
var loki = require('lokijs');
var db = new loki('loki.json');
var clientes = db.addCollection('clientes');

    function mounted(fn) {
        if(document.readyState != 'loading'){
            fn();
        }else{
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
        }
    }

    mounted(function(){
        document.querySelector('#salvar').addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                let data = {
                    nome:document.querySelector('#nome').value,
                    cpf:document.querySelector('#cpf').value,
                    endereco:document.querySelector('#endereco').value,
                    telefone:document.querySelector('#nome').value,
                    placa:document.querySelector('#placa').value,
                    compania:document.querySelector('#compania').value

                };
                clientes.insert(data);
                db.save();
                alert('Cadastrado com sucesso');
                document.querySelector('#cadastro-cliente').reset()

        })
    })
```

HTML

```
<script>
    require('./renderer.js');
    var read = require('read-file-utf8')
    var loki = require('lokijs');
    var db = new loki('loki.json');
    var data = read(__dirname+'/loki.json');
    db.loadJSON(data);
    window.vue = require('vue');
    //db.loadJSON()
    var clientes = db.getCollection('clientes');
    console.log(db);

        new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            clientes: [],
            client:{
              nome:'',
              cpf:'',
              endereco:'',
              telefone:'',
              placa:'',
              compania:''
            },
          },
          mounted: function(){
            this.clientes = clientes.data;
            console.log(this.clientes);
          },
          methods:{
            editClient: function(cliente){
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
             this.clientes.fill(cliente);
            },
            createClient:function(){
              $('#myModal').modal('show');
              this.client={
                nome:'',
                cpf:'',
                endereco:'',
                telefone:'',
                placa:'',
                compania:''
              };
              db.save();
            },
            deleteClient:function(){
              this.data.chain().remove();
            },
          }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Provavelmente você está inserindo o ID do item salvo nas variáveis e quando tenta salvar novamente, está enviando o mesmo id. Provavelmente. Veja as suas variáveis antes de salvar a primeira vez, o que é retornado depois disso e as variáveis quando for salvar na segunda vez.